# The group of rotation of a cube is isomorphic to $S_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Proof of my book is here

> Since the group of rotations of a cube has the same order as $S_4$, **(1)we need only prove that the group of rotations is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_4$**.To this end, observe that a cube has four diagonals and that the rotation group induces a group of permutations on the four diagonals. But we must be careful not to assume that different rotataions correspond to different permutations. To see that this is so, **(2)all we need to do is show that all 24 permutiations of the diagonals arise froem rotations.** Labeling the consecutive diagonals 1,2,3, ans 4, it is obvious that there is a $90^\circ$ rotation that yields the permutation $\alpha = (1234)$; another $90^\circ$ rotation about an axis perpendicular to our first axis yields the permutation $\beta=(1423)$ So, the group of permutations induced by the rotations contains the eight-element subgroup $\{\epsilon, \alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3,\beta^2,\beta^2\alpha,\beta^2\alpha^2,\beta^2\alpha^3\}$ and $\alpha\beta$, which has order. Clearly, then, the rotations yield all 24 permutaions, **(3)since the order of the rotation group must be divisible by both 8 and 3**

Q.1 I don't understand why we only need to check (1).  and where can I find that (1) is satisfied  ?

Q.2 Suddenly why do we need to show (2) instead of showing (1). what (2) is related to (1) ?

Q.3 How can we know (3) is satisfied, I think (3) only to show the order of the rotations group is multiple of 24, not exactly 24

Answer (score 3):

(1) You know that $|G|=24$, therefore any injective homomorphism $G\hookrightarrow S_4$ is automatically an isomorphism.
The action of $G$ on the set of the four spacial diagonals gives us a homomoprhism $\phi\colon G\to S_4$, but is it injective?

(2) Now, contrary what (1) hints to, the author tries to show that $\phi$ is onto, not that it is 1-1. Then again, it does not matter: An onto homomorphism between two finite groups of same order is of course also an isomorphism. I agree that this is confusing. They should have formulated (1) differently.

(3) $\phi(G)$ contains a subgroup of order $8$ and a subgroup of order $3$, hence $\phi(G)$ has order a multiple of $24$. However, we already know that $|\phi(G)|\le |G|\le 24$.

---

Alternatively, 120° rotations around a diagonal fix that diagonal and cyclically permutes the other three. And a 180° rotation around the line through the midpoints of two opposing edges fixes two diagonals and swaps the other two. We conclude that the stabilizer of one diagonal is the full $S_3$ of the other three diagonals. As the rotations of the cube clearly act transitively on the diagonals, it follows that $\phi(G)$ has order $4\cdot |S_3|=24$, i.e., is the full $S_4$ of the four diagonals. Again, from $|G|=24$ we conclude that $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

(It is not part of the quoted text, but I assume the author established $|G|=24$ in a similar argument: $G$ acts transitively on the six faces, and the stabilizer of one face is a cyclic group of four rotations, therefore $|G|=6\cdot 4$.)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I understand what author want to show. but one thing I want more is that how the function $\phi : G \rightarrow S_4$ works in detail. I'm hard to imagine how to works the function. you mean for  $R_{90^\circ} \in G $ s.t $\phi(R_{90^\circ})=\alpha =(1234)$? and then how to know that $\phi  (G)$ contain all eight element by knowing only two element ($\alpha, \beta$) contained in $\phi (G)$?