# Wikipedia says that the center of S4 is trivial. Is it?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Wikipedia says that the center of the symmetric group n>=3 is trivial.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_(group_theory)#Examples

But IIRC, S4 is the same group as the rotations of a cube, and the group of rotations of a cube has an abelian subgroup Z2×Z2 consisting of the rotations by 180 degrees, which is nontrivial.

So ... what's going on?

Comment: Abelian subgroup means that the elements commute among all each other. There may be well none of them (except the identity) which commutes with all the elements of the parent group.

Comment: While the center is an abelian subgroup, not every abelian subgroup is central. An element is central in $S_4$ if it commutes with *every* element of $S_4$. And $S_4$ is **not** the rotations of the cube. That's smaller. It is the permutations of a set of four elements.

Comment: Rotations of a cube has 24 elements - same as s4. Each one of six faces can be on top, and that top face can be in 4 possible orientations. Doesn't mean it *is* s4, but apparently it is. Not sure I see the connection, though.

Comment: @PaulMurrayCbr Oh, I see. I think the connection is through the four diagonals that connect opposite pairs of vertices. Think of rotations as permuting the diagonals, verify any nontrivial rotation yields a nontrivial permutation of the diagonals.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin hmm. each diagonal can be in two orientations, so it would need to be the case that permuting them "chooses" an orentation for each. For instance, if we mark the tip of the four diagonals red at the end where they touch the 6 on the dice, each permutation needs to keep all those four red spots together around a square.

Comment: Ignore the orientation. Just consider the diagonal (equivalently, unordered pairs of pairs of opposite vertices). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2765402).

Comment: Plus one for thinking for yourself.   Play around with these things is the right idea.

Comment: Something even weirded can happen. There are groups whose every proper subgroup is abelian, yet they have trivial centre. Can you find one? ($S_4$ is not one of them.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement $S_4$ has an abelian subgroup $H=\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ means that every element in $H$ commutes with other element in $H$. This does not mean that every element in $H$ commutes with all the elements in $S_4$. So this does not imply $H\leq Z(S_4)$.

Comment: It's not necessary that *every* (nontrivial) element in $H$ commute with all the elements of $S_4$ to solve OP's conflict. *Some* suffices, which yields a nontrivial center either.

Comment: So, rather, $H$ abelian does not imply $|H\cap Z(S_4)|>1$.

Comment: Yep - rotating my pen left and then flipping vertically does not produce the same result as flipping vertically and rotating it left. And there it is.

Answer (score 3):

Not every abelian subgroup of a group is central.   Examples abound.

Let's see, to take a few, any finite group divisible by a prime $p$ has a (cyclic) subgroup of order $p$, by Cauchy's theorem (which is abelian).  But that subgroup needn't be central.   The $S_n'$s ($n\ge3$) indeed provide infinitely many examples.

So you're confusing the definitions. Central elements commute with *every* element of the parent group.

And, this may be a little like beating a dead horse now but, by Cayley's theorem, *any* finite abelian group embeds in an $S_n$.